# Linking different elements together

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to link several different elements together so that one specific class element can activate an action on another specific class element (for instance, if `.ph5` is clicked, `.art5` will be visible)

This is what I have so far:

```js
var back = [$(".art1"), $(".art2"), $(".art3"), $(".art4"), $(".art5"), $(".art6"), $(".art7"), $(".art8"), $(".art9")];
var front = [$(".ph1"), $(".ph2"), $(".ph3"), $(".ph4"), $(".ph5"), $(".ph6"), $(".ph7"), $(".ph8"), $(".ph9")];

$('front').click(function(e) {
  var clicked = $(e.clicked);
  for (var i = 0; back.length; i++) {
    if (clicked.is(front[i])) {
      back[i].show();
    }
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for me. Is there something wrong with my code and/or is there a better way to "link" multiple classes together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you gave them all the same common class it is even simpler. You can get an index from a collection of elements using `index()` and use `eq()` to match another set of elements (assumes both sets in same order)

```
var $front = $('.ph'); // all have same class
$front.click(function(){
   var index = $front.index(this); // index of element clicked within collection
   $('.art').hide().eq(index).show();  // hide all,then show the matching index  
});
```

References:

[index() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

[eq() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x9gs5bLb/)**</kbd>

Comment: This would work, but what if his `front` has different element count or order with `back`?

Comment: @Bandon far more common they are same order, especially if they are dynamically created

Answer (score 1):

Thought there is a more simple way to do it by using jquery selector `element[attr^='value']`, which can select all `elements` with `attr` start with `value`.

```js
$("div[class^='ph']").click(function() {
  var newid = $(this).attr("class").replace("ph", "art");
  $("." + newid).show();
});
```

```css
.art1,
.art2,
.art3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ph1">ph1</div>
<div class="ph1">ph1</div>
<div class="ph2">ph2</div>
<div class="ph2">ph2</div>
<div class="ph3">ph3</div>
<div class="ph3">ph3</div>
<br>
<div class="art1">art1</div>
<div class="art1">art1</div>
<div class="art2">art2</div>
<div class="art2">art2</div>
<div class="art3">art3</div>
<div class="art3">art3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the array element using `front[i]` and `back[i]`. you can rather create the object of array and access elements by `.eq()` selector:

```
$(front).click(function(e) {
  var clicked = $(e.clicked);
  for (var i = 0; back.length; i++) {
    if (clicked.is($(front).eq(i))) {
    $(back).eq(i).show();
  }
 }
});
```